# In CloudKit, how can you sort a CLLocation by timestamp when using CKQuery?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am making a CloudKit request that will potentially have many CKRecords returned to the user (lets say around 1000). These records currently only contain a single custom property that is of type CLLocation. I have data being returned from the server and it is in chunks of 100 at a time since that is the CloudKit limit. I am using the returned cursor to retrieve the next set until I have retrieved all 1000 items. The data being returned is route data, and I don't need all 1000 items to start using the beginning of the route. However, to do this I need the items to be returned in the order of the location timestamp (this is historical route data, so if I get it out of order I would need to wait until I have everything and sort it on the client side).

My question is, how can I sort the CLLocation data on the server by it's timestamp property? I am trying to avoid introducing an extra timestamp property on the CKRecord since the location already has this data. So far, here is what I have tried:

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "GPSRoute", predicate: predicate)
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "location.timestamp", ascending: false)]
```

But this returns in error when I submit the CKQuery. I have also tried using CKLocationSortDescriptor, but this seems to only sort based on relative location between points which will not work for me.

Does anyone how to sort CKRecords on the server by a CLLocation's timestamp property? Here is the error I am getting:

```
<CKError 0x14a325cf0: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2000); server message = "Unknown field 'CKFieldName{_name='location.timestamp'}'"; uuid = XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX; container ID = "iCloud.com.mywebsite.myapp">
```

Comment: Update your question with the error message.

Comment: It has been updated.